# If the following error message displays, what can I do to have my app working?

Tags: installation, pepper, nao-robot, installation-package, choregraphe

I downloaded the app on my laptop and when I tried to open it an error message displays : "The code execution cannot proceed because VCOMP120.DLL was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem." and I reinstalled it many times:(. What can I do to be able to use this application?

Comment: search the web for VCOMP120.DLL

Comment: What operating system and version of choreograph are you trying to install?

Answer (score 0):

Something must be wrong in your Windows installation, according to [this post in Microsoft's community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/missing-vcomp120dll/5c751829-368c-46af-ac37-98197f130c53).